# Created package in Laravel workbench, but how to transfer to vendor folder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, workbench

Let's say my package in Laravel is *test/test*.

I created the package in the workbench and it's been working great following [Jason Lewis' tutorial](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-4-develop-packages-using-the-workbench). Now I want to move the package out of 
the workbench to the vendor directory. This is where **all tutorials fall short**, even the laravel docs. I didn't want to use git to move the files, so I simply copied the test/test package from the workbench to the vendor directory (and then deleted it from the workbench). I didn't copy the test/test/vendor folder from the workbench (or any other files I noticed in the .gitignore file). I then ran *composer install* from my new vendor/test/test directory. I then did a *composer dump-autoload* from the laravel root directory.

Now when I run my application I get an error that I did not get when the package was in the workbench:

```
Class 'Test\Test\TestServiceProvider' not found
(this is coming from \bootstrap\compiled.php on line 4121)
```

I also did a *php artisan dump-autoload* from the laravel root and I get this same error.

Any ideas? Or can someone lead me to a tutorial that takes the package development all the way to it's final resting point in the vendor directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working.

I added:

```
"psr-0": {
    "Test\\Test": "vendor/test/test/src/"
}
```

to the autoload section in composer.json in the laravel root directory so it looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Test\\Test": "vendor/test/test/src/"
    }       
},
```

If I decide to put the package on [Packagist](http://www.packagist.org) later then I might remove this from the autoload and just keep the package referenced in the "require" part of my composer.json. We'll see what happens when I get that far!

Comment: Though, it is in your vendor folder, which is excluded from your git commits (by default).  I would suggest making something like `app/lib` so when you move to production, you don't have to move it manually and it persists in your repo.  Just change out the psr-0 path.

Comment: I just edit that .gitignore file and right under `/vendor/*` I add `!/vendor/Test`

Comment: Thanks for this, I've been having the exact same issue, and your question resolved my problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can install your packages from your hard drive as from local repository like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type":"vcs",
        "url":"/path/to/repo/here"
    }
],
"require":{
     "me/myrepo":"dev-master"
}
```